# SQL, Problema GROUP BY

Tags: sql

tengo el siguiente problema al ordenar unos registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, estoy intentando filtrar unas ventas y me salen campos duplicados: por ejemplo las tapas...

Debería ir ordenado por NomFam "Nombre de familia".

Cambiando de orden el GROUP BY:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que si no pongo esos GROUP BY me da error de agrupación...

Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: Intenta poner el NomFam primero en el `GROUP BY`

Comment: Nada... he editado la pregunta con el ejemplo que propones.

Comment: Pon código no imagenes @Adrian Hernando Solanas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás agrupando `ImporteBruto`, y que estás confundido con la forma de obtener el porcentaje. Si entiendo correctamente, el porcentaje es sobre el total de importe bruto de tus datos filtrados, que es un dato diferente al que estás calculando.

Una forma rápida de obtener lo que estás buscando sería usando la siguiente consulta (asumiendo SQL Server 2005+):

```
SELECT  CodFam,
        NomFam,
        SUM(Unidades) Cantidad,
        SUM(ImporteBruto) Total,
        SUM(ImporteBruto) / SUM(ImporteBruto) OVER() Porcentaje
FROM dbo.PI314_Detalle_Facturas
WHERE codlocal = 12
AND FechaContable = '17/05/2018' -- esta columna es datetime/date?, en ese caso usa '20180517'
AND ImporteBruto <> 0
GROUP BY CodFam,
         NomFam
;
```

Answer (score 1):

El orden y la agrupación son independientes... Tienes que agregar una cláusula `order by` para ordenar de la forma que quieras:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
group by NomFam, CodFam, ImporteBruto
order by NomFam, CodFam, ImporteBruto
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que pides esto:

```
 DECLARE @total decimal(15,5) = (SELECT SUM(ImporteBruto) from PI314_Detalle_Facturas)
 SELECT  CodFam,
    NomFam,
    SUM(Unidades) Cantidad,
    SUM(ImporteBruto) Total,
    SUM(ImporteBruto) * 100 / @total Porcentaje
 FROM dbo.PI314_Detalle_Facturas
 WHERE codlocal = 12
 AND FechaContable = '17/05/2018' 
 AND ImporteBruto <> 0
 GROUP BY CodFam,
     NomFam
 ORDER BY NomFam, CodFam
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega **order by NomFam** y si quieres para que lo ordene por otras campos agregar  **order by NomFam,CodFam,ImporteBruto**